# How to change window url without redirection or reloading of page?

Tags: web

When I click on "Liked By" below an instagram post, it shows a popup of the list of people who liked that post. Somehow, it also changes the url from `www.instagram.com` to `www.instagram.com/p/<some random alphanumeric text here>/liked_by/`. As you see, the url has changed without the page being reloaded and there is no # in there either. How is this done?

I've a .NET background but I'm not up to date on the latest web technologies and this question is technology agnostic because I don't know what technology instagram uses but feel free to point me in the right direction and I'll research the .NET equivalent of what's going on.

Comment: This answer may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `history.pushState` method, it allows you to push a url to the history of navigated pages and it will change the url reference to the value you passed. In the examples you provided, it would be like this:

```
history.pushState({}, "some title", "/p/<some random alphanumeric text here>/liked_by/")
```

It accepts both relative and absolute paths.

All this is done via javascript on the browser-side, I don't think you can do this without javascript. If you want to check the history api, you can [check it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method).

Comment: Ah, just for curiosity, this is what frameworks as Angular and React uses, you can check here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/search?q=history.pushState&unscoped_q=history.pushState and
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/package.json#L47

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.